# Self-signed certificate for 127.0.0.1 not accepted by Chrome

Tags: c#, windows

Before Chrome 58, I was able to use a self-signed certificate with CN=127.0.0.1 and have Chrome accept it as long as it was in my Trusted Root certificate store.

Chrome 58 stopped accepting self-signed certificates that do not have alternative names. From my searching it seems that providing the alternative name should fix the issue, so I used this PowerShell command:

New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "Testing" -DnsName "127.0.0.1", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(50)

I then placed a copy of that certificate in Trusted Root Authorities.

Now, if I browse to https://127.0.0.1 I get "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID", but it does accept the certificate if I browse to https://localhost.

I'm wondering if there is any way to generate a certificate from New-SelfSignedCertificate that will work the way it used to before Chrome 58, ie. just by adding it to Trusted Root.

Mainly I'm trying to avoid either having to add the certificate manually in Chrome's own certificate list, having to change any settings in Chrome to allow insecure localhost certificates, or having to create 2 certificates (1 to be root and 1 to be signed by root). I'm guessing I can get it to work with one of those workarounds but those were not necessary before, so I'd just like to confirm if Chrome 58 changed something else (other than requiring the subject alternative names) that breaks the process I was used to.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/self-signed.html You might use Jexus Manager to generate a self signed certificate, which sets the alternative name automatically.